# Is it ok to use LinearLayout.LayoutParams in case I don't need advanced functionality?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-linearlayout, android-actionbar-compat

I've noticed that some Android views come with a custom version of `LayoutParams`, e.g. when adding an `ActionBar` to a `LinearLayout` I could set its dimensions like this:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, actionBarSize);
actionBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But as you can see, this is extremely wordy. So I tried using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead, which makes it much shorter and better readable, like so:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, actionBarSize);
actionBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I've tried both versions and they seem to do exactly the same.

That's what makes me wonder whether it's ok to just go with `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` in case I don't need any advanced functionality provided by custom versions such as `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams`?

Or does using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` for `ActionBar` (and similar cases) have any potential unwanted side effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `ActionBar.LayoutParams` inherit from 
`ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. Thus, they both behave the same for width and height attribute.

For reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams